# How to make a pull request to Visual Studio Online

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, pull-request, azure-devops

I use Visual Studio Online (VSO), and few days ago the VSO team announced support of pull requests.

I would like to ask, is it possible to forbid commits without a pull request from Visual Studio 2013?

I mean, that I want forbid my team to commit changes, until they pull request first, to allow the repository owners to accept or decline changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea behind pull requests, [as now (June 2014) supported by Visual Studio Online](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/06/10/git-pull-request-visual-studio-online.aspx), is to have two upstream repositories:

- one accepting pull requests
- one from which pull requests are done.

[image: http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-45-92-2014-06-pull_2D00_requests/4405.VCtrlGitPullReqNew2.png]

So, as long as the team has only access to the second repository, and are not members of the first repositories, they will only push to that second repository. They couldn't push to the first.

If they want their commits to show up in the first repository, they won't have any other way than making a pull request, which should be what you want.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is exactly what I want. It is not so user friendly as could be, but it is acceptable for me.